# Evaluate $\int_{2}^{\frac{2}{3}}\int_y^{2-2y}(x+2y)e^{y-x}dxdy$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

> > Evaluate $$\int_{2}^{\frac{2}{3}}\int_y^{2-2y}(x+2y)e^{y-x}dxdy$$

My try:

I actually started using the transformation $$u=x+2y, v=y-x$$

But I am really not sure, how to frame the limits for $u$ and $v$. Any HINT please?

Comment: Draw your region in $xy$, then figure out the equation of each of the boundaries in terms of $uv$

Comment: Also are you sure your $y$ bounds are correct? They look backwards

Comment: Yes correct they go from $\frac{2}{3}$ to $2$. I will EDIT.

Comment: If those are backwards then your $x$ bounds are backwards as well.

Comment: No need to change of variable. Simply integrate inside w.r.t. $x$, and then w.r.t. $y.$

Comment: @AnneBauval pedagogically this is good practice since changing variables is faster, and the problem can then be verified by doing the problem with integration by parts.

Comment: Changing variables is not faster, on the contrary it is time consuming. Moreover, it may cause errors. Integration by parts can be done directly.

Comment: Hint (if you insist on changing coordinates): check the images of the vertices in the $(x,y)$ triangle under your transformation.

Comment: Since the exercise is quite simple, I'll give you only a hint. It's good to learn to solve such exercises on your own, as they are fundamental in the standard courses of universities, and there are many similar exercises solved in the books provided for free by the state to our students.

Hint: First find the integrals $\int e^{-x}dx$ and $\int xe^{-x}dx$ If you can solve them, then you will be able to solve the exercise as the same integrals appear there.

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int_{2}^{\frac{2}{3}}\left[\int_y^{2-2y}(x+2y)e^{y-x}\ dx\right]\ dy=\int_{2}^{\frac{2}{3}}e^{y}\left[\int_y^{2-2y}(x+2y)e^{-x}\ dx\right]\ dy$$

$$I=\int_{2}^{\frac{2}{3}}e^{y}\left[-e^{-x}(x+2y+1)\right]_y^{2-2y}\ dy$$
$$I=\int_{2}^{\frac{2}{3}}e^{y} [-3e^{2y-2}+e^{-y}(3y+1)]\ dy$$

$$I=\int_{2}^{\frac{2}{3}}(-3e^{3y-2}+3y+1)\ dy=e^{4}-\frac{23}{3}$$